# Call controller method from action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have my base controller and action filter in the same namespace but in different classes.  I created a class inside of the base controller which requests http headers, and I would like to call that method inside of my action filter.

If I do a simple `Details dtls = GetHeaders()` the intelliSense asks if I want to create another method `GetHeaders()` inside of the action filter.

So my question is can I call the `GetHeaders()` method inside of the `BaseController` class directly from the action filter?  How would I do so? If not, how could I call that method?

```
namespace Infrastructure
{
    public class BaseController
    {
        public Details GetHeaders()
        {
            //Get the headers
        }
    }

    public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

            //Call GetHeaders() to get Header1 data
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried getting the controller from the `filterContext`

```
var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;

controller.GetHeaders();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/BaseController/GetHeaders");
    }
}
```